# How fix "Refused to load script" error on Android cordova app

Tags: cordova

I'm getting a refused to load script error when I run my cordova app on the Android platform

I've uninstalled and reinstalled `cordova-plugin-whitelist`. I've added `<access origin="*" />` to my `config.xml`. The whole works.

This is the error message

```
Refused to load the script 'file://www.radiojar.com/wrappers/api-plugins/v1/player.js?1.65.1t' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: 
"script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' http://www.radiojar.com/wrappers/api-plugins/v1/player.js http://www.radiojar.com/wrappers/api-plugins/v1/jplayer/jplayer.js http://now-dot-playing-dot-radiojarcom.appspot.com/api/stations/u31u2awpxbwtv/now_playing/". 
Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Here is my `config.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget android-versionCode="2" id="org.christsheart" version="1.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Christs Heart</name>
    <description>
        Christ's Heart app.
    </description>
    <author email="info@christsheart.org" href="https://christsheart.org">
        Christ's Heart
    </author>
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <access origin="*" />
        <allow-navigation href="*" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
        </edit-config>
        <icon density="ldpi" src="res/android/ldpi.png" />
        .....
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        ....
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" spec="~2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="~2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="~3.0.0" />
    <engine name="android" spec="^8.0.0" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="^5.0.0" />
    <engine name="browser" spec="^6.0.0" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is because you are missing some permissions, try

```
 script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *;
```